# SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SHOWN or SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED?

Tags: ubuntu, window, sdl, sdl-2

What is the difference between these two window event types? I've looked at [this documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEventID), but it didn't give very detailed descriptions. I'm trying to get an SDL application to redraw itself after being un-minimized, and my current solution is to handle both event types. Handling just `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED` does not work on Ubuntu MATE 1.24.0.

Comment: Compare the bounding-boxes between the two events.  I suspect `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SHOWN` will end up being the entire window's client surface (or at least whatever is visible) whereas `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED` will only be whatever part of the window was un-obscured (assuming a classic, non-compositing windowing system).

Comment: @genpfault Sorry, I'm not sure how to check the bounding-boxes. Is that information associated with the `SDL_WindowEvent` structure?

Comment: Hmm, for some events the width/height will be in `data1` & `data2` but looking closer that might not be the case for these two, sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

When using Xorg the `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SHOWN` is generated by SDL at least in the following [cases](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/cc152103ba11c890848c991d7ddf281b3b1f1e14/src/video/x11/SDL_x11events.c#L463-L472):

1. When a `MapNotify` event is received from the X server;
2. When the window looses the `SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN` flag;
3. When the window gains the `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN` flag;

In regards to cases 2 and 3 the comment in SDL source code [mentions](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/cc152103ba11c890848c991d7ddf281b3b1f1e14/src/video/x11/SDL_x11events.c#L1425-L1429):

> ...
> Compositing window managers can alter visibility of windows without
> ever mapping / unmapping them, so we handle that here ...

Per the [X Window System Glossary](https://x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#glossary:Mapped) unmapped windows are never shown:

> A window is said to be mapped if a map call has been performed on it.
> Unmapped windows and their inferiors are never viewable or visible.

The `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED` event is generated by the SDL when it receives the `Expose` event from the X server.

The [X Window System Glossary](https://x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#glossary:Exposure_event) says this about the "exposure" events:

> Servers do not guarantee to preserve the contents of windows when
> windows are obscured or reconfigured. Exposure events are sent to
> clients to inform them when contents of regions of windows have been
> lost.

Based on this data it appears that the `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SHOWN` event will be generated whenever a window changes state from hidden to visible and the `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED` event will be generated when any part of the window becomes obscured.